# ConnectableObservable vs flatMap() self-references?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I was curious about use cases for the `ConnectableObservable` and thought maybe it could be helpful to turn expensive emissions from a cold observable (like from a database query) and emit them as hot. That way expensive replays could be avoided, and a single set of emissions would be pushed to all operators and subscribers.

After some thought experiments however, I had some concerns that self-references in flatMaps could cause issues.

For example, say I emit values 1 to 10 through a `ConnectableObservable`. But I `flatMap()` each value to the sum of all the values, and then subtract the current value.

```
    ConnectableObservable<Integer> source = Observable.range(1,10)
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .publish();

    source.flatMap(i -> source.reduce(0,(x,y) -> x + y).map(sum -> sum - i))
            .subscribe(sum -> System.out.println("SUM - i: " + sum));

    source.connect();
```

My hope was that I would get this output.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
SUM - i: 54
SUM - i: 53
SUM - i: 52
SUM - i: 51
SUM - i: 50
SUM - i: 49
SUM - i: 48
SUM - i: 47
SUM - i: 46
SUM - i: 45
```

But instead I got this.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
SUM - i: 53
SUM - i: 50
SUM - i: 46
SUM - i: 41
SUM - i: 35
SUM - i: 28
SUM - i: 20
SUM - i: 11
SUM - i: 1
SUM - i: -10
```

As I feared, the `flatMap()` looks like it needs a replay of the values as it cannot deal with the hot sequential nature of the source. So if I use a `cache()` operator, then everything works fine because the cached values will replay for each `flatMap()` operator.

```
    Observable<Integer> source = Observable.range(1,10)
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .cache();

    source.flatMap(i -> source.reduce(0,(x,y) -> x + y).map(sum -> sum - i))
            .subscribe(sum -> System.out.println("SUM - i: " + sum));
```

These are my questions:

1. What exactly happened with this `ConnectableObservable` process? It looks to be deterministic so how did it come up with those values?
2. Is it safe to say that `ConnectableObervable` can be dangerous to self-reference in any operators that use it? And `cache()` should be the go-to hot operator in these circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly happened with this ConnectableObservable process? It looks to be deterministic so how did it come up with those values?

This setup is non-intuitive but what happens is that the inner sums don't exist until their respective starting value is created and each of them only sees the original sequence one element after their creation. For example, for 1, the inner sum will get events starting from 2 to 10 only.

> Is it safe to say that ConnectableObervable can be dangerous to self-reference in any operators that use it? And cache() should be the go-to hot operator in these circumstances?

The problem isn't with `ConnectableObservable` but with `publish` which is time sensitive and `Subscriber` sensitive: who is there receives events, who isn't there won't get anything retroactively.